# How can I verify if Make is doing its up-to-date check correctly?

Tags: makefile, stat

I've run into a situation in which a file is clearly up to date (say, `bar`), but running `make --trace` for a file that depends on it (say, `foo`) results in it being remade again and again with a message like

```
Makefile:16: update target 'foo' due to: bar'
```

I say "again and again", but that's not entirely correct. If I keep running `make foo` repeatedly I'll get

```
make: 'foo' is up to date.
```

For all but the first of the calls. But if I go and run `make jez` (considering `jez` as something that also depends on `bar` and only it), `make` will rebuild `jez`, and if I proceed to `make foo` again it will be rebuilt again (the first time).

During all that time, `bar`, the source of both `jez` and `foo`, remains untouched -- and indeed `make bar` outputs `make: 'bar' is up to date.` at any time.

Comment: Hard to answer without a MWE... !

Answer (score 0):

The answer is http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/. It will solve all your problems.

In my specific case up there, the problem was that `make foo` and `make jez` were deleting the entire directory (where `foo` and `jez` should be) before recreating it and outputting stuff into there. MY problem was that `make --trace` didn't explicitly say that to me, but `remake --trace` did.

Comment: Did you try `make -d`?